# jQuery remove part of an image source

Tags: jquery, replace

```
$('.modal-left img').data('src').replace('-90x67','');
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Using the above code I am trying to remove `-90x67` from the image source specified. I'm unable to do so using it, could someone assist?

Comment: What does the html look like? Because the code works http://jsfiddle.net/JK7z3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.modal-left img').attr('src').replace('-90x67','');
```

---

Or better [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$('.modal-left img').prop('src').replace('-90x67','');
```

---

If you want to replace it use and set replaced `src`

[.prop( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)

```
$('.modal-left img').prop('src',function(_,old){
   return old.replace('-90x67','');
});
```

---

Read [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) here:

```
$('.modal-left img').attr('src').replace('-90x67','');
```

or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
$('.modal-left img').prop('src').replace('-90x67','');
```

Your code only works if you put your image source inside `data-src` attribute

```
<img data-src="Your image src here" src="Your img src here" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var test=$('.modal-left img').attr('src').replace('-90x67','');

$('.modal-left img').attr('src',test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your image attr as follows:

```
// To Change It
$('#test img').attr('src', 'new value');

// To Remove It
$('#test img').removeAttr('src');
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AAyss/1/